# Using internationalized domain name with Route 53 and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I would like to expose static web page hosted on Amazon S3 to the world under following address:

```
zolty.aaa
```

What's more, I would like to redirect users from following addresses:

```
zol-ty.aaa
żółty.aaa
żólty.aaa
... and all combinations of z-ż, o-ó, etc..
```

to the main address - zolty.aaa. Of course all domains were bought.

When it comes to first domain name it's quite easy.

1. Set up zolty.aaa in Route53 as ALIAS to zolty.aaa S3 bucket
2. Set up zol-ty.aaa in Route53 as ALIAS to zol-ty.aaa S3 bucket
3. Redirect all request (in S3 bucket settings) from zol-ty.aaa to zolty.aaa

Unfortunately it's not that simple if domain contains non ASCII characters.

Based on [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html#domain-name-format-idns) punycode should be used for internationalized domain names.

So now my domain looks as follows:

```
xn--ty-4ja03asj.aaa
```

I am able to create hosted zone in Route 53 with such name. Now I want to create S3 bucket and add ALIAS to this bucket in DNS (Route53). Based on Amazon documentation, the name of S3 bucket should be the same as domain name. So I'm creating bucket xn--ty-4ja03asj.aaa. But it's not visible in Route53 as a possible target of ALIAS.

How can I achieve described behaviour?

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html) 
What you need to do is:

1. Convert your domain to `punycode`: https://cryptii.com/pipes/punycode
2. Create a hosted zone and set that `punycode` as a domain name;
3. Add the nameservers from your hosted zone to the domain control panel ;

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets must be created using [punycode](https://cryptii.com/pipes/punycode) with the initial `xn--` removed.

The punycode name for the domain `żółty.aaa` would be `xn--ty-4ja03asj.aaa`. The S3 bucket created must therefore be `ty-4ja03asj.aaa`.

As an aside, if using Cloudfront you then set the origin as `ty-4ja03asj.aaa.s3-website-<region>.amazonaws.com` or if simply pointing from Route 53 use `s3-website-<region>.amazonaws.com` after having selected "Alias to S3 website endpoint".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [S3 bucket names must not start with the prefix xn--](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html)

[The need](https://binx.io/blog/2022/01/31/s3-website-hosting-why-your-domain-name-and-bucket-name-must-be-identical/) for having the same domain and bucket name only applies if you set it up through Route 53 directly. If you set it up with CloudFront the bucket and domain don’t have to be identical.

I used one of the [tutorials](https://www.stormit.cloud/post/setup-an-amazon-cloudfront-distribution-with-ssl-custom-domain-and-s3) out there in order to associate my IDN with my s3 static website.